# Determine groups in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, dictionary, reduce

I am trying to determine groups in a string.

For example "***AAABBCCCCD***" should have ***["AAA", "BB", "CCCC", "D"]*** as groups based on the pattern in the string.

Here is my simple function to do that:

```
const patternGroup = (str) => {
  let cursor = str[0]
  let groups = []
  let currentGroup = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let ch = str[i]
    if (ch === cursor) {
      currentGroup += ch
    }
    else {
      groups.push(currentGroup)
      currentGroup = ch
      cursor = ch
    }
  }
  if (currentGroup !== "") {
    groups.push(currentGroup)
  }
  return groups
}
```

It works as intented but I am looking for a simpler function, maybe using map/reduce or regex. Any ideas?

Comment: Questions asking for design suggestions in working code are more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to your implementation:

```
const patternGroupWithReduce = (str) => {
  let currentGroup = ""
  return str.split("").reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    currentGroup += cur
    if (str[i + 1] !== cur) {
      acc.push(currentGroup)
      currentGroup = ""
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
}

const patternGroupWithRegex = (str) => {
  return str.match(/(.)\1*/g)
}
```

RegEx **/(.)\1*/g** uses the back reference for the capturing group.

\1* matches the same char as recently captured one as many times as possible.

Here is the visualization for it:
[image]

Comment: I also added jsperf: https://jsperf.com/pattern-group for anyone to see and compare.

Answer (score 6):

you can simply use RegExp:

```js
var input = "AAABBCCCCD";
const res = input.match(/([^])(\1*)/g);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: this regexp? it says `find any character , then if that character still exist, catch it until not found the character` . [lean more about regexp](https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-regex/)

Comment: I recomment you add that to your answer, comments can get removed :)

Comment: The pattern `[^]` seems strange, why not `.`? And why do you have the second capture group?

Comment: `[^]` accepts every character like spaces , but `.` do not. the second capture has no reason :)) just for readability.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
(.)\1*
```

As in:

```js
let string = "AAABBCCCCD";
let rx = /(.)\1*/g;
let parts = string.match(rx);
console.log(parts);
```

See a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6HqoAJ/1).